# Howto configure OpenNMS JMXMonitor

Tags: java, opennms

There is jmx bean with value "true/false". 
I'd like to add a monitoring using that bean via JMXMonitor.

Unfortunately, there is no do about that at all.
"JMX Configuration Generator" will not help as it generates config for collectd, which works with numeric data.

Any advice would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JMX Monitor](http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/20.0.2/guide-admin/guide-admin.html#poller-jmx-monitor) which allows you to run tests against the value of a given bean. Check out the example "Test a specific management bean for a value".

A service would look the following:

```
<service name="JMX-BeanValue-Test" interval="300000" user-defined="false" status="on">
    <parameter key="retry" value="3"/>
    <parameter key="timeout" value="3000"/>
    <parameter key="port" value="18980"/>
    <parameter key="beans.connected" value="org.opennms.workflow:name=client.onms.connected"/>
    <parameter key="tests.isConnected" value="connected.get(&quot;Value&quot;) == true"/>
</service>

<monitor service="JMX-BeanValue-Test" class-name="org.opennms.netmgt.poller.monitors.JmxMonitor"/>
```

Hope this helps for further troubleshooting

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thank you for the hint, added the essential parts in the answer.